# Изменить высоту textarea в зависимости от контента

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как сделать, чтобы при большом количестве текста размер textarea менялся (по высоте)? У меня появляется полоса прокрутки, а нужно, чтобы он автоматом увеличивал высоту textarea.

Если можно добиться этого, не используя скрипт на чистом css, - было бы очень здорово!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться готовым [решением](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/), это готовый плагин JS (jQuery), который называется Autosize.

Answer (score 0):

как через CSS я не знаю, но можно через js:

```js
let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];

textarea.addEventListener('input', resizeTextarea);

function resizeTextarea() {
  textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";

  while (textarea.style.height.slice(0, -2) >= textarea.scrollHeight) {
    textarea.style.height = textarea.style.height.slice(0, -2) - 1 + "px";
  }
  while (textarea.style.height.slice(0, -2) > textarea.scrollHeight) {
    textarea.style.height = textarea.style.height.slice(0, -2) + 1 + "px"
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  height: 1px;
  min-height: 30px;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```